# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, printing

I have a textbox in which user will write some text.

Now If he wants to print that text he should click on print button.
The design of Print button is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" Enabled="False" OnClientClick = "CallPrint('txtReadFiles')" />
```

Now in the head part of aspx page the function CallPrint is declared as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CallPrint(strid)
        {
            var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
            **var docwrite=prtContent.innerHTML;**
            var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,toolbar=0,status=0');
            WinPrint.document.open();
            WinPrint.document.write(docwrite);
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
            WinPrint.close();
        }
    </script>
```

But when I click on print button I get an error on line marked with **

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you have an element with the ID `txtReadFiles` ?

Comment: And, if you have a `txtReadFiles`, what is it?

Comment: Yes I have. It is a textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thats probably because this line `var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);` fails i.e. returns null.
is the textbox you are trying to get also a server control ? If so then during runtime its id would change ,if this indeed is the issue look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392958/getting-id-from-asp-net-runat-server-in-jquery)

Comment: Yes, it is a server control. I mean I write runat = "server" while declaring that textbox. Why should its ID change? I always access it as txtReadFiles. and I don't understand any thing on that link.

Comment: Sorry for the comment above. I got my answer from your link. Thanks.