# Hiding asp.net button when a certain tab is selected jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a page with tabs setup and an asp button.

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:700; height:1000">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Referral</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnMainSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />    
</div>
```

When tabs-3 is selected, I want the button to be invisible but visible for the first two tabs. How can I achieve this using jquery baring in mind that I am a beginner. I have tried the following code but it hasn't worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
    $('#tabs, #tabs-3').tabs({
        active: function (event, ui) {
            $("#btnMainSave").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Rob

Comment: The problem here is that is a server side ID and you are client side, have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392958/getting-id-from-asp-net-runat-server-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) event (not the [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option):

```
$(function () {
    $('#tabs, #tabs-3').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            $("#btnMainSave").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

#### Edit

You'll have to add some logic to check which panel is being activated, and hide the `button` based on that. I don't know which version of jQuery UI you're using, but the following will work in the latest:

```
activate: function(e, ui) {
  $('#btnMainSave').toggle( !$(ui.newPanel).is('#tabs-3') );
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prMQJ/1/)

Comment: I've made the change to activate and now its behaving a bit strangely. The button shows on the first tab but disappears from the 2nd and 3rd tab and when I go back to the first tab afterwards, its missing from there too.

Comment: You need to add some logic to check if the tab is `tab3` when activated

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjMFz/)**

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```