# unable to open jquery dialog on a linkbutton click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

note that i'm using asp.net with vb.net

jquery:

```
$("#create")
.button().click(function () {
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});

$("#LinkButton3").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
```

asp:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit" id="create"></a>
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the dialog opens for the a tag but does not open for the linkbutton can anyone tell me why my code is not working?

Comment: You need the client id of your link button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392958/getting-id-from-asp-net-runat-server-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of `linkbutton` on client side would be different so use the `ClientID` to bind the event. Also put binding code indocument.ready. Assign a class to linkbutton and use class selector to bind event.

*Html*

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" class="someclass">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>    <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit" id="create"></a>
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('.someclass').click(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

If you need to use id for select then use attribute selector with starts with wild card.

```
$('[id=^LinkButton3]').click(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientID` to get server control in jquery like this.

```
  var create= "#<%=create.ClientID%>";
    $(create).on('click', function() { 
      $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
```

Don't forget to include js file and js code inside document.ready .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add UseSubmitBehavior="false" to your asp link button

your html

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit" id="create"></a>
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinkButton` is server side asp.net controls which causes `postback`. Another point is you are not using the correct id of the control it's changed. Try with $('#`<%=LinkButton3.ClientID%>')`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you link button with this

```
<asp:LinkButton ClientIDMode="Static" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

see this:

**ClientIDMode="Static"**