# How can I get value ID from ascx code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-jsom

[image: ascx code behind]

[image: ascx]

[image: javascript file]

I have 3 pics above. I don't know how to declare variable in JavaScript to get value from ascx and code behind.

Comment: If your "javascript file" is a .js, then be advised that you can't use `<%=` in a .js file.  Only .ascx files are parsed for server-side variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code as below to get the hidden value using jQuery code.

```
var libraryName = $("input[id$='hdnLibraryName']").val();
```

Example:

**.ascx code**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnLibraryName" runat="server"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var libraryName = $("input[id$='hdnLibraryName']").val();
        console.log(libraryName);
    });
</script>
```

**.ascx.cs code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.hdnLibraryName.Value = "Library1126";
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**ALL CREDIT GOES TO:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392980/9357872

Add a class then get the value of the class:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnLibraryName" runat="server" CssClass="library"/>
```

Then:

```
var LibraryName = $(".library").val();
```