# Hiding a div with JQuery

Tags: jquery

My div is inside a user control, it shows a "successful" message after a gridview update.
I don't want that div to be persistent and want to hide it after a few seconds without refreshing the page.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="MsgInfo" runat="server"  class="divMsg" visible="false" /></div>
```

In my usercontrol I added the link to the script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../HideMsg.js"></script>
```

The script:

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { 
       $("#MsgInfo").fadeOut(1500); 
    }, 
    5000);
});
```

I don't know what is missing there but the message can't fade out or disappear.

I went through a lot of similar question and solution but still can't hide the div with Jquery.

Comment: Still not working, the he div remains persistent and does not fade out. Could this be because the update button is in the edit mode of the formview in my user control?

Answer (score 1):

Check this working example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/musama125/pen/vYpoEXG)

Inside update click you need to use setTimeout

```
$("#showDiv").click(function () {
   $("#MsgInfo").fadeIn(1500);

   setTimeout(function () {
     $("#MsgInfo").fadeOut(1500);
   }, 5000);
});
```

CSS:

```
#MsgInfo {
  display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` name instead of `id`. The reason is you are using `asp.net` control `GridvView` with `runat server`. So it will have updated value for id (try inspecting element on browser and check `id`). So, instead of using `id` selector try using `class` selector. Try like below.

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { $(".divMsg").fadeOut(1500); }, 5000);
});
```

You can also refer this answer here : [Getting ID from asp.net runat server in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392958/getting-id-from-asp-net-runat-server-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If #MsgInfo div comes after page load then try to add script inside #MsgInfo div.

```
 <script>   
 const myTimeout = setTimeout(myMsgInfo, 5000);
    
    function myMsgInfo() {
      var x = document.getElementById("MsgInfo");
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your div closing tag use `<div>..</div>` not `<div/>...</div>`

```js
$(function () {
setTimeout(function () { $("#MsgInfo").fadeOut(1500); }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="MsgInfo" runat="server"  class="divMsg" visible="false">It will hide after 5 seconds</div>
```

Comment: Made the correction to my div tag, but it is not working.
Could this be because the update button is in the edit mode of the formview in my user control. The div is outside the formview.

Comment: Then please check your JS file it should be at the bottom of your HTML.